# Is there any way to make Graphics.TranslateTransform() permanent?

Tags: c#, graphics, transform, translate

I am using the Graphics class to draw a legend followed by a heat map.

As I draw the heat map, I am calling TranslateTransform() to work on a specific part then ResetTransform() before moving onto the next part.

After I draw the legend, I'd like to permanently shift my graphics matrix by the legend's height such that ResetTransform() always returns to below the legend. Currently, every time I ResetTransform(), I have to Restore() to my base origin (below the legend).

Comment: No but as you can save the transform data you can load them on each start of the drawing routine. Do note the Save and Restore calls must match!! To avoid that you can store and reload the Matrix yourself. - Or, maybe, you find a good use of [GraphicsContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.begincontainer?view=netframework-4.8)